# How to check if move_uploaded_file function has error

Tags: php

i have the following code for uploading the file on my folder and it is working on localhost, but when i uploaded the code online, it's not working though i have put the correct path. Is there any way i could see the reason or error why?

```
 move_uploaded_file($img_tmp,"../images/profile/$post_image1");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about directory permissions for your destination? Have you cross-checked that?

```
try chmod -R 777 /var/www/your_project_name
```

This might help :)

Also, check what's your function move_uploaded_file is returning?

"Returns TRUE on success.

If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued."

Comment: where will i supposed to add that line of code? under my move_uploaded_file?

Comment: can you help me how to check what it is returning? i don't know how to do it :(

Comment: That part of code is for the folder permission where you are saving the uploaded file. There is possibility that your folder 'profile' may not have the writeable permission. 

Therefore, use the linux terminal and add the permission using the above code. 
chmod  is used to change the access permission of a file system and 777 is the code which will give full permission for that folder.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! this is for my final project. and this is the last problem i got. :)

Comment: Good luck, then. I hope this might have helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, refer the below code:

```
$move = "path_where_you_want_to_save_the_file."
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $move . $_FILES["file"]['name'])) {
    echo "Uploaded";
} else {
   echo "File was not uploaded";
}
```

To check what the function returns:
Just simply use `return(move_uploaded_file($img_tmp,"../images/profile/$post_image1"));`